# Display Dialog Bitmap

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap

Hi all I am fairly new to win api and am using C. I was wondering how would I display a banner on my dialog application. I have managed to load the application icon with the following code.

```
LoadIcon(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
```

However am a little unsure on how to do it on dialog. Using visual studio I was able to create the picture control box which gives me IDC_STATIC1 do I use sendmessage to load the bitmap file?

Sorry if its a dumb question I have had a good route on google this morning but no sucess.

Comment: you say banner, but you want to set the dialog's icon, right?

Comment: sorry I didnt make that clear no its just a logo which will appear in the main IDC_DIALOG window i.e company logo not the top icon bar however if you could shed light on that as well it would be much appreciated. I take it I would need to define and and add a .ico 16x16 size?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the image from the resources of your app:

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage (
    hInst, 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), 
    IMAGE_BITMAP, 
    0, 0, 
    LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
```

If you want to load the image from an external file:

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage (
    0, 
    path, 
    IMAGE_BITMAP, 
    0, 0, 
    LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

Now you want to display an image in the client area of your Dialog Box, well you have to *blit* it.

```
HDC hdcDst = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
BitBlt(hdcDst, x, y, width, height, sourceDc, xSource, ySource, mode);
```

Consider that you are doing all this the hard/old way; after the direct SDK calls came  Visual C++/MFC/.NET/WPF/...

Comment: also if you want to use icons instead of images, here's a good explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648051

Comment: thanks I give it a try later on thanks a lot for you reply I though I would learn the old way then the new now I know why they made it easier lol. I would vote for your answer but an new today so cant vote yet.

Comment: since you're @RupertMurdoch I'll be happy with a coupla million dollars instead of the vote. :)

Comment: You don't have to blit it.  You can send STM_SETIMAGE to a static control and let Windows take care of it.